# How do I save Firebase JSON data into a variable in Node.JS

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've figured out how to save and retrieve date from Firebase but, I am having problems savings the JSON into a variable. I have set the variable to usersDB but, when I console.log() the variable, It logs out as *undefined*

```
//firebase setup
var db = admin.database(); 
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog"); //var for databaseURL


//firebase
var usersRef = ref.child("users"); //where I am pulling the data from
var usersDB // init var

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val()); // logs the way I want it
     usersDB = snapshot.val(); // trying to save json
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed:" + errorObject.code);
})

console.log(usersDB) // logs undefined

app.get("", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", {users : usersDB});
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.user.username);
    usersRef.child(req.body.user.username).set({
        name:  req.body.user.name,
        email: req.body.user.email,
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the variable into another function and save it there:

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val()); // logs the way I want it
     func_(snapshot.val()); // trying to save json
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed:" + errorObject.code);
})

function func_(json){
   console.log(json) // logs undefined
}
```